# Execute Git processes that require a passphrase from within a groovy script

Tags: git, shell, groovy

I'd like to be able to automate several >git commants from within a Groovy script.  I'd like to execute a process using code like the following...

```
def cmd = "${GIT_EXEC} submodule update --init ";
def process = cmd.execute(null, new File('.'));
process.consumeProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
process.waitFor();
rc = process.exitValue();
```

**Here's the problem...**

When you enter that command manually, you get prompted to enter your key passphrase.  Using my groovy script, you don't get prompted and the script just hangs.  :(

I have seen several other posts related to this area.  The consistent response was to use something called `ssh-agent`.  That tool is not on my Windows box, nor on the Windows boxes of the other developers & admins on the project.  I don't want to ask them to find a windows-friendly version of that and install it.

Here is where my situation is different from those others:  I don't need to prevent the shell from prompting for a passphrase.  I'd be delighted if the prompt would happen through my groovy script, the user could type it, and life would continue normally.

Is there a fancy way I can tell the process I invoke from within Groovy to go ahead and interact with the user, and not merely swallow the prompt?

What options do I have here?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a pure-java Git client library like [jgit](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=technology.jgit) to interact with git, instead of spawning a process?